# can't access members of PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

[image]

This JSON I have converted to an array in PHP.
when i get the sizeof or count, the array size is 1
Do you not get an associative array using json_decode in PHP?
after the JSON below you see i echo out the typeof, so you see it is array, then size of, and you see it is 1
Any idea why I cant access the value for 'name' in the resulting array and why it is of size 1?

Comment: How about you show some code instead of meaningless screenshots?

Comment: $resumeCurr = Resume::where('id', '=', $theresume)->get();
    echo $resumeCurr;  //is this JSON?

      $res[] = json_decode($resumeCurr, true);

      echo gettype($res);

      echo count($res);
       echo $res['name'];

Comment: As I can see, you've got array with one element which is object or assoc array (depends on second parameter in json_decode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `count` is returning `1` is because your JSON is structured in such a way that it represents an *array of objects*, of which you only have 1 (note the single set of braces). If you would like to count all elements within the first and only object in your JSON array, you could instead try:

```
count($json[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin realized that. I now have a string but even that is just too messy to bother working with. back to the drawing board

Answer (score 1):

Well, look at the JSON. It's an array of an object.

`echo $json_decoded[0]->name; // chemist`

`var_dump` may be useful next time.